# SQL reading a column as a regular syntax

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I keep getting this error

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 97
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Group'

I think SQL is reading it as a syntax like `GROUP BY` because it showing it in blue color, how can I fix this?

[image]

Query:

```
SELECT  
    SUM(s.TotalDue)
FROM
    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] s
INNER JOIN  
    SALES.SalesTerritory t ON s.TerritoryID = t.TerritoryID
WHERE       
    t.Group '%North America%'
```

Comment: You're missing a comparison operator after `t.Group`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the column name in the square bracket as `Group` is a SQL Server keyword.

```
SELECT  SUM(s.TotalDue)
FROM    [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] s
INNER JOIN  SALES.SalesTerritory t
ON     s.TerritoryID = t.TerritoryID
WHERE  t.[Group] like  '%North America%'
```